# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore: Ambiguous use of 'set(_:forKey:)'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I'm using Xcode 8.3 beta 2 (8W120l) and can't get this line of code to work:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default().set(["one", "two"], forKey: "key")
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Ambiguous use of 'set(_:forKey:)'
```

This piece of code compiles perfectly on Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002).

I can't find any info on how to get this code compile.

[image]

Comment: So strange. Did you try `set(["one" : "two"], forKey: "key")` just to see if it works with a dictionary instead of an array? My first thought is it's a beta bug

Comment: By the way you have the coolest reputation score right now!

Comment: Have you tried extracting the argument to an explicitly-typed constant (`let value: [String] = ["one", "two"]`)?

Comment: @crizzis thanks for the suggestion! It works if I extract the argument, so it must be a beta thing.

Comment: @crizzis can you submit it as answer? It still holds after so many years.